# Genetic Algorithm - Fitness function and Rule optimization

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

Let's say I have a set of training examples where `A_i` is an attribute and the output is `Iris-setosa`

The values in the dataset are

```
A1, A2, A3, A4      outcome
3   5   2   2       Iris-­setosa
3   4   2   2       Iris­-setosa
2   4   2   2       Iris­-setosa
3   6   2   2       Iris­-setosa
2   5   3   2       Iris­-setosa
3   5   2   2       Iris­-setosa
3   5   2   3       Iris­-setosa
4   6   2   2       Iris­-setosa
3   7   2   2       Iris­-setosa
```

from analysis the range of attribute are:

```
A1 ----> [2,3,4]
A2 ----> [4,5,6,7]
A3 ----> [2,3]
A4 ----> [2,3]
```

I have defined:

```
A1 ----> [Low(2),Medium(3),High(4)]
A2 ----> [Low(4,5),Medium(6),High(7)]
A3 ----> [Low(<2),Medium(2),High(3)]
A4 ----> [Low(<2),Medium(2),High(3)]
```

I have set like below:

```
A1,         A2,         A3,         A4          outcome
Medium      Low         Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa     
Medium      Low         Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
Low         Low         Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
Medium      Medium      Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
Low         Low         High        Medium      Iris-setosa
Medium      Low         Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
Medium      Low         Medium      High        Iris-setosa
High        Medium      Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
Medium      High        Medium      Medium      Iris-setosa
```

I know I have to define the **fitness function**. What is it for this problem? In my actual problem there are **50** training examples but this is a similar problem.

How can I optimize rule by using `GA`? How can I encode?

Suppose if I **input (4,7,2,3)**, how optimization can help me classify whether the input is `Iris-setosa` or not?

Thank You for your patience.

Comment: @IrtizaKhanNiloy do you want to generate the Iris-setosa class with genetic programming? Why is the outcome always Iris-setosa? Sorry just having a bit of trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The task you describe is known as [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification).

Identifying elements of a specific class amongst all elements, by learning from a training set containing only the objects of that class is

> ... different from and more difficult than the traditional classification problem, which tries to distinguish between two or more classes with the training set containing objects from all the classes.

A viable approach is to build the outlier class data artificially and train using a two class model but **it can be tricky**.

When generating artificial outlier data you need a wider range of possible values than the target data (you have to ensure that the target data is surrounded in all attribute directions).

The resulting *two-class* training data set tends to be unbalanced and
large.

Anyway:

- if you want to try Genetic Programming for one-class classification take a look at

  *[One-Class Genetic Programming](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~mheywood/X-files/Publications/rcurryEuroGP10.pdf) - Robert Curry, Malcolm I. Heywood (presented in EuroGP'10, the 13th European conference on Genetic Programming)*
- also consider the [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) techniques (a simple introduction is the 9th week of the [Coursera Machine Learning class](https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture) by Andrew Ng; [notes](http://dnene.bitbucket.org/docs/mlclass-notes/lecture16.html) here).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you just want to know how to program a fitness function... Assume training data is list of tuples as so:

```
training_data = list((3,6,3,5),(8,3,1,2),(3,5,2,4)...)
```

Make a reference set for elements of A1, A2, etc. as follows, assuming first tuple tells us length of all the others (that way you can have any number of tuples in your training data):

```
A=[]
for x in training_data[0]:
    res_list = set()
    res_list.update(x[index] for x in training_data)
    A.append(res_list)
    index+=1
```

Now all your reference data is easily referred to (sets of A[0], A[1] etc). Let's make a fitness function that takes a tuple and return a fitness score that will help a GA converge on a right answer (1-4 if right elements, 5+ if in training_data). Play around with the scoring but these should work fine.

```
def fitness_function(target):
    # Assume target is a tuple of same length as reference data
    global A, training_data
    score = 0
    # Give a point for each element that is in the data set
    index = 0
    for t in target:
        if t in A[index]:
            score+=1
        index += 1 
    # Give 5 points if entire tuple is exact match
    if target in training_data:
        score+=5
    return score
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a multi-class classification problem that can be solved with Genetic Programming and related techniques.

I suppose that data are those from the well-known Iris data set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set

If you need a quick start, you can use the source code of my method: Multi Expression Programming (which is based on Genetic Programming) which can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/mepx/mep-basic-src

There is a C++ source name mep_multi_class.cpp in the src folder which can "solve" iris dataset. Just call the read_training_data function with iris.txt file (which can also be downloaded from dataset folder from github).

Or, if you are not familiar with C++, you can try directly MEPX software which has a simple user-interface: http://www.mepx.org. A project with iris dataset can also be downloaded from github.